# Can I generate a collaboration diagram using sequence diagram in StarUML?

Tags: uml, sequence-diagram, staruml, collaboration-diagram

Is it possible to do this automatically?or do i have to do it manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check Model - Convert diagram option.

Comment: In which version this option is available. ?

Comment: @kammy, The original StarUML (referred as 5.0 or 1) + all versions of WhiteStarUML

Answer (score -1):

Seems like this feature is not available anymore.
Version 3.0.2